# Unable to import Drive

Tags: java, android

I am facing the problem in Drive. I am unable to import it. The error I am getting is that `DriveScopes` cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Context context;
    private static Uri callLogFileUri;
    private static Uri smsLogFileUri;
    private static Drive service;
    private boolean callLogs;
    private boolean smsLogs;
    private String address;
    private ContentResolver cr;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.backup_layout);

      progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      context = this;
      Intent intent;
      cr = getContentResolver();
      credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,DriveScopes.DRIVE);

      try {
          intent = getIntent();

          if (intent.hasExtra("fromReceiver")) {
              address = intent.getStringExtra("fromReceiver");
              Log.i(TAG, "Backup intent from receiver");
              recoverData();
          } else {
              Log.i(TAG, "Backup intent from elsewhere");
              DialogFragment dialog = new BackupAccountsDialogFragment();
              dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),
                      "BackupAccountsDialogFragment");
          }

      } catch(Exception e) {
          recoverData();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {
      case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
          final String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
          if (accountName != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST ACCOUNT PICKER");
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            service = getDriveService(credential);
            storeGoogleAccounts(accountName);
            Log.i(TAG, "Account saved: " + CHOSEN_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT + " " + accountName);
            getFirstAuthInAsync();
          }
```

Comment: `Drive service` does compile?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jar of Drive with your IDE (something like Eclipse)?

If not, then you have to do that. So javac can find the import path.

Comment: Now do you have a .jar file? Whats it name? And where is it now?